# Не понимаю в чём проблема (динамические массивы структур)

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры

Задание: сделать массив из структур(содержание структуры это информация про ваших друзей, имя фамилия и т.д.). При желании пользователя пополнять список. 
Код ниже компилируется, но вот при выполнении какая-то лажа и если честно я в замешательстве.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct pBook
{
    char name[100];
    char surname[100];
    char adress[100];
    char pNumber[100];
}*PhoneBook;

void init(pBook *a, int &size);
void addData(pBook*a, int size);
pBook* add(pBook *a, int &size);
void showFriendList(pBook *a, int size);

void main()
{
    int size = 1;
    PhoneBook = new pBook[size];
    init(PhoneBook, size);
    cout << "Your frined list." << endl << endl;
    showFriendList(PhoneBook, size);
    cout << "\n\nInfo about Oksana." << endl << endl;
    aboutOksana(PhoneBook, size);
    delete[]PhoneBook;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
}

void init(pBook *a, int &size)
{
    char s;
    do {
        addData(a, size);
        cout << "Wanna add new friend?\ny/n\n";
        cin >> s;
        cin.ignore();
        if (s == 'y') a = add(a, size);
    } while (s == 'y');
}

void addData(pBook*a, int size)
{
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    gets_s(a[size - 1].name, 100);
    cout << "Enter surname: ";
    gets_s(a[size - 1].surname, 100);
    cout << "Enter adress: ";
    gets_s(a[size - 1].adress, 100);
    cout << "Enter phone-number: ";
    gets_s(a[size - 1].pNumber, 100);
}

pBook* add(pBook *a, int &size)
{
    pBook *temp = new pBook[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        strcpy_s(temp[i].name, strlen(a[i].name) + 1, a[i].name);
        strcpy_s(temp[i].surname, strlen(a[i].surname) + 1, a[i].surname);
        strcpy_s(temp[i].adress, strlen(a[i].adress) + 1, a[i].adress);
        strcpy_s(temp[i].pNumber, strlen(a[i].pNumber) + 1, a[i].pNumber);
    }
    delete[]a;
    size++;
    a = new pBook[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        strcpy_s(a[i].name, strlen(temp[i].name) + 1, temp[i].name);
        strcpy_s(a[i].surname, strlen(temp[i].surname) + 1, temp[i].surname);
        strcpy_s(a[i].adress, strlen(temp[i].adress) + 1, temp[i].adress);
        strcpy_s(a[i].pNumber, strlen(temp[i].pNumber) + 1, temp[i].pNumber);
    }
    delete[]temp;
    return a;
}

void showFriendList(pBook *a, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << i + 1 << ". ";
        cout << "Name = " << a[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Surname = " << a[i].surname << endl;
        cout << "Adress = " << a[i].adress << endl;
        cout << "Phone-number = " << a[i].pNumber << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Путём усилий и труда я нашёл косяк, просто функции возвращают теперь указатель на наш массив.
Вот рабочее решение моего кода(мб оно не совсем оптимальное, но рабочее).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct pBook
{
    char name[100];
    char surname[100];
    char adress[100];
    char pNumber[100];
}*PhoneBook;

pBook* init(pBook *a, int &size);
pBook* addData(pBook*a, int size);
pBook* add(pBook *a, int &size);
void showFriendList(pBook *a, int size);
void aboutOksana(pBook *a, int size);

void main()
{
    int size = 1;
    PhoneBook = new pBook[size];
    PhoneBook = init(PhoneBook, size);
    cout << "Your frined list." << endl << endl;
    showFriendList(PhoneBook, size);
    cout << "\n\nInfo about Oksana." << endl << endl;
    aboutOksana(PhoneBook, size);
    delete[]PhoneBook;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
}

pBook* init(pBook *a, int &size)
{
    char s;
    do {
        a = addData(a, size);
        cout << "Wanna add new friend?\ny/n\n";
        cin >> s;
        cin.ignore();
        if (s == 'y') a = add(a, size);
    } while (s == 'y');
    return a;
}

pBook* addData(pBook*a, int size)
{
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    gets_s(a[size - 1].name, 100);
    cout << "Enter surname: ";
    gets_s(a[size - 1].surname, 100);
    cout << "Enter adress: ";
    gets_s(a[size - 1].adress, 100);
    cout << "Enter phone-number: ";
    gets_s(a[size - 1].pNumber, 100);
    return a;
}

pBook* add(pBook *a, int &size)
{
    pBook *temp = new pBook[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        strcpy_s(temp[i].name, strlen(a[i].name) + 1, a[i].name);
        strcpy_s(temp[i].surname, strlen(a[i].surname) + 1, a[i].surname);
        strcpy_s(temp[i].adress, strlen(a[i].adress) + 1, a[i].adress);
        strcpy_s(temp[i].pNumber, strlen(a[i].pNumber) + 1, a[i].pNumber);
    }
    delete[]a;
    size++;
    a = new pBook[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        strcpy_s(a[i].name, strlen(temp[i].name) + 1, temp[i].name);
        strcpy_s(a[i].surname, strlen(temp[i].surname) + 1, temp[i].surname);
        strcpy_s(a[i].adress, strlen(temp[i].adress) + 1, temp[i].adress);
        strcpy_s(a[i].pNumber, strlen(temp[i].pNumber) + 1, temp[i].pNumber);
    }
    delete[]temp;
    return a;
}

void showFriendList(pBook *a, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << i + 1 << ". ";
        cout << "Name = " << a[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Surname = " << a[i].surname << endl;
        cout << "Adress = " << a[i].adress << endl;
        cout << "Phone-number = " << a[i].pNumber << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void aboutOksana(pBook *a, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(a[i].name, "Oksana") == 0) {
            cout << "Info about " << a[i].name << " " << a[i].surname << endl;
            cout << "Name = " << a[i].name << endl;
            cout << "Surname = " << a[i].surname << endl;
            cout << "Adress = " << a[i].adress << endl;
            cout << "Phone-number = " << a[i].pNumber << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы несколько рефакторизовал вашу программу (часть с Оксаной опущена) - если оставаться в рамках обычного C с выводом через `cout` (по сути, это единственное, что отличает вашу программу от программы на C) - *для начала* до

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct pBook
{
    char name   [100];
    char surname[100];
    char adress [100];
    char pNumber[100];
};

void   fill(pBook*&a,    int &size);
void   addData(pBook*&a, int &size);
void   showFriendList(pBook *a, int size);

int main()
{
    pBook* PhoneBook     = nullptr;
    int    PhoneBookSize = 0;
    fill(PhoneBook, PhoneBookSize);
    cout << "Your frined list." << endl << endl;
    showFriendList(PhoneBook, PhoneBookSize);
    //cout << "\n\nInfo about Oksana." << endl << endl;
    //aboutOksana(PhoneBook, size);
    delete[] PhoneBook;
    cin.get();
}

void fill(pBook*&a, int &size)
{
    for(char s = 'y'; s == 'y'; (cin >> s).ignore())
    {
        addData(a,size);
        cout << "Wanna add new friend?\ny/n\n";
    };
}

void readString(const char * prompt, char * field, int size = 100)
{
    cout << "Enter " << prompt << ": ";
    gets_s(field, size);
}

void addData(pBook*&a, int& size)
{
    pBook *temp = new pBook[size+1];
    if (a) memcpy(temp,a,sizeof(pBook)*size);
    delete[] a;
    a = temp;

    readString("name",        a[size].name);
    readString("surname",     a[size].surname);
    readString("address",     a[size].adress);
    readString("phone-number",a[size].pNumber);

    ++size;
}


void showFriendList(pBook *a, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << i + 1 << ". ";
        cout << "Name = " << a[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Surname = " << a[i].surname << endl;
        cout << "Adress = " << a[i].adress << endl;
        cout << "Phone-number = " << a[i].pNumber << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

По крайней мере от двойной пересылки всей памяти туда-назад при добавлении одной записи точно надо избавляться.... Следующим шагом я бы прибавлял не один элемент, а удваивал размер зарезервированного массива.

Вот как мне представляется этот код на C++ (естественно, разных решений может быть масса):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class PBook
{
    string name, surname, address, phone;
public:
    PBook(const char * name = ""):name(name){}
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const PBook&);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream&, PBook&);
    friend bool operator < (const PBook& a, const PBook& b) { return a.name < b.name; }
};

ostream& operator << (ostream&os, const PBook&p)
{
    os << "Name:    " << p.name    << endl;
    os << "Surname: " << p.surname << endl;
    os << "Address: " << p.address << endl;
    os << "Phone:   " << p.phone   << endl;
    return os;
}

istream& operator >> (istream& is, PBook& p)
{
    cout << "Name:    "; getline(is,p.name);
    cout << "Surname: "; getline(is,p.surname);
    cout << "Address: "; getline(is,p.address);
    cout << "Phone:   "; getline(is,p.phone);
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    multiset<PBook> pb;
    for(char s = 'y'; s == 'y'; (cin >> s).ignore())
    {
        PBook p; cin >> p; pb.insert(p);
        cout << "Wanna add new friend (y/n)? ";
    };

    cout << "-----------\nYour frined list:\n";
    for(auto p: pb) cout << p << endl;

    cout << "-----------\nYour Oksana list:\n";
    auto ox = pb.equal_range("Oksana");
    for(auto it = ox.first; it != ox.second; ++it)
        cout << *it << endl;

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Я уже переделал своё решение, сделал код менее объёмным и более быстрым, у вас тоже интересное решение.
P.S. от обычной сишки мой код ещё отличает оператор выделения памяти new, насколько помню в чистой си malloc, calloc, realloc и т.д.

Comment: Это все непринципиальные отличия. Хорошо, я добавлю "по сути" в ответ :) Давайте так - загляньте через часик-другой - сейчас просто некогда - я попробую интереса для переписать ваш код на C++.